# need to understand the use of "/" in sed command

Tags: linux, sed

I want to understand the sed command

For example I have the command:

```
rtNum=`pwd | sed -e 's/^.*bbsp.\/rt//' -e 's/\/.*$//'`
```

and

```
rtRun=`pwd | sed -e 's/^.*bbsp.\/rt.*\///'`
```

where pwd is: `/tfsrun/bbsp2/rt3/run`
it produces the output as:

```
echo $rtNum 
3
```

and

```
echo $rtRun 
run
```

I want to understand the above sed command especially the use of `-e` and the use of /'s, // and /// in the above sed command.

Comment: You can find your questions answered in sed manual.

Comment: I went through the sed manual as provided, but not able to resolve my queries.

Comment: @ZumodeVidrio That is more or less true for _every_ question here.

Answer (score 4):

As the manual states, the `-e` option tells that a script is following.
Your script is replacing matching content with an empty string by using a regular expression.

To understand regular expressions, I recommend to take a sufficient amount of time to read e. g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-regular-expressions.htm

To your question:
`\/` are escaped slashes, which means those will not be treated as a separator.
`/` are the separators to separate the matching string from the target string

e. g. `'s/matchingstring/targetstring/'` s invokes the replacing of the first occurrence of matchingstring with targetstring.

In your case:

- `'//'` means targetstring is empty since there is nothing in between the separators
- `'///'` actually is `'\///'` which means matchingstring ends with a slash and targetstring is empty.

Comment: The _script is not a regular expression_, it is a `s` (substitute) `sed` command whose syntax is `s�regexp�replacement�[flags]`. Where `�` can be any character (though limited to single byte ones in some `sed` implementations) though `/` is the most often used characters, as that's also the  one used for line addresses expressed as regexps as in `sed '/regexp/='`

Answer (score 1):

The `-e` flag to `sed` is a way of saying "execute/run this".  It is needed if you want to run several `sed` editing commands in the same `sed` invocation (unless you separate them with `;` instead).

For example, for extracting/printing only lines 1 and 20 through to 30 from a file (the `-n` flag turns off the default output of every input line):

```
$ sed -n -e '1p' -e '20,30p'
```

In `sed`, single forward slashes (`/`) are used to delimit regular expressions.

For example, deleting all lines that contains the string "hello" followed by "word" later on the same line:

```
$ sed '/hello.*world/d'
```

You may see a double forward slash in substitutions sometimes. The `s` command in `sed` performs a substitution of something matching a regular expression with a string:

```
s/pattern/replacement/
```

If the intention is to *delete* the thing matched by the pattern, the replacement will be empty, and we will end up with

```
s/pattern//
```

The triple forward slash (`///`) comes from someone trying to delete a pattern *ending with a slash*. Since slashes are used as delimiters, you'll also notice that the first slash is *escaped* with a backslash (`\/`) forming `\///`. "Escaped" means "made to be treated as a literal character, not as a delimiter".

There are a couple of other ways to work around the awkward slashes when doing a substitution in `sed`.  Take the substitution

```
s/\///
```

This deletes the first `/` on each line (actually *replaces with nothing*).

An alternative is to write

```
s/[/]//
```

This puts the slash in a character group, or *bracket expression*.  All characters in such a group are always treated as literal characters by `sed`. A bracket expression only matches *one* character out of the character listed within it.

Another approach is to use another delimiter:

```
s#/##
```

Here, the `#` character takes the role of delimiter (one may pick any character).  To match a `#` when using `#` as a delimiter, one has to use either `\#` or `[#]`, just as one had to do when using the default `/` delimiter.

So, looking at the `sed` command line

```
sed -e 's/^.*bbsp.\/rt//' -e 's/\/.*$//'
```

This performs two editing operations:

1. `s/^.*bbsp.\/rt//`  or  `s#^.*bbsp./rt##`
2. `s/\/.*$//`         or  `s#/.*$##`

Both are substitutions (the `s` editing command in `sed`), and both replaces the pattern that it matches with nothing, i.e. they both delete something from the input.

The first pattern is `^.*bbsp.\/rt` and will match from the start of the line (`^`), any number of any characters (`.*`), followed by the string `bbsp`, followed by some other character (`.`) and the string `/rt`.

So it looks like it will delete everything on the line up to and including the `/rt` after `bbsp.`, where `.` represents any character.

The second pattern, `\/.*$`, will match anything after a `/` to the end of the line (`$`).

So given the line of text

```
/tfsrun/bbsp2/rt3/run
```

The first substitution will turn it into

```
3/run
```

and the second will turn it into

```
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are quotes from `man sed`

> **-e script, --expression=script**
>
> ```
>   add the script to the commands to be executed
> ```
>
> **s/regexp/replacement/**
>
> ```
>   Attempt to match regexp against the pattern space.  If successful, replace  
>   that  portion  matched  with  replacement.  The replacement may contain the
>   special character & to refer to that portion of the pattern space which
>   matched, and the special escapes \1 through \9 to refer to the corresponding
>   matching sub-expressions in the regexp.
> ```